# android.support.v4.animation missing in API 26

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-gradle-3.0

I am facing an issue: `android.support.v4.animation.*` is missing and I cannot find any solution.

> Android Plugin upgrade to 3.0 requires `buildToolsVersion` and `compileSDKVersion` to 26+ and this package is missing.

Comment: How are you adding the above library?

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0' @PeterHaddad

Comment: please check my answer here it maybe the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47355843/gradle-error-after-android-studio-update

Comment: Have already added the `google()` repository.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't find `android.support.v4.animation.*` in 26+ seemingly because min SDK version has been increased to 14 from `26.0.0 Alpha 1` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-0-0-alpha1):

> Note: The minimum SDK version has been increased to 14. As a result,
>   many APIs that existed only for API < 14 compatibility have been
>   deprecated. Clients of these APIs should migrate to their framework
>   equivalents as noted in the reference page for each deprecated API.

Many new classes, methods, and constants added to provide backwards-compatible support for platform APIs added in O Preview as specified [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/26.0.0-alpha1/changes.html).

Hope you're using 26+ support lib version for `com.android.support:appcompat-v7`. Notice diff in `ItemTouchHelper` from below 26 and 26+. One includes `android.support.v4.animation.*` other doesn't and uses classes from `android.animation` package:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, but what is the solution . I am trying to use ItemTouchHelper which uses `android.support.v4.animation.*`. @random

Comment: Use the platform package `android.view.animation.*`

Answer (score -1):

supportLib 26.0.0+以上AnimatorCompatHelper class be remove

so clearInterpolator(view) not found

we can to use：

`TimeInterpolator mDefaultInterpolator = new ValueAnimator().getInterpolator();
view.animate().setInterpolator(mDefaultInterpolator);`

Comment: Your answer seems to be right, however please try to write english sentences which everybody can understand. It's very hard right now. Also your answer lacks some "prove" (e.g. a link to the changelog). Please edit your question and add those.