# "Gradle error after Android Studio update"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Today I updated Android  Studio to version 3.0
And after that I couldn't build project successfully.
I got these errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
```

I tried using VPN or proxy etc. but none of them worked.
It's been a long day. I hope you may help me.

This is my build.gradle(app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.hetbo.kotlin_tutorial"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

and this is build.gradle(project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I did a lot of things to fix it but every time it failed.

I use gradle 4.3.1

And here is gradle wrapper properties :

```
#Sat Nov 18 10:16:45 IRST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3.1-all.zip
```

Comment: What's your gradle version ?

Comment: It's version 4.1

Comment: Try with version `4.3` also provide your build.gradle(project)

Comment: I updated to 4.3 and now I get this error : gradle failed error input sting "<!"

Comment: show us the file of build.gradle(project)

Comment: Edited. Take a look.

Comment: This is a new project. There nothing written to be checked.

Comment: @HoseinSaad Also add `debug{ ... }`, similar to release block inside buildTypes block, in your app module's build.gradle  file.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with gradle. When I use SDK v26 build finishes successfully but I wanna use 27 which I can't.

Comment: What is your google repository version?

Answer (score 4):

with the new features of **gradle 4.1** and the **classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'**

> distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists
>   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
>   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

and and this is build.gradle(project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Still Not Working

Comment: Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/Hetbo/AndroidStudioProjects/Kotlin_Tutorial/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for &#39;:app@debug/compileClasspath&#39;: Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1.">Show Details</a>

Comment: Need to see `gradle-wrapper.properties` as well.

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: Try to change `distributionUrl` to `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`

Comment: first when I updated it was 4.1 and gradle failed so I updated to 4.3 and 4.3.1 but none of them helped

Comment: try `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/g‌​radle-3.3-all.zip` and
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3`

Comment: well I did this before and yes downgrading gradle worked but I wanna use latest version and wanna know what's wrong with it.

Comment: I did and failed again. I don't know what to do anymore. I'll downgrade until new version :(

Answer (score 0):

As of the new versions, the libraries are now inside the `maven` not inside `Jcenter`.

So inside your gradle file, you have to add `maven` like the below:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
 }
```

This link may help you: [Adding support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

Comment: where did you add `maven`?

Comment: build.gradle(project)

Answer (score 0):

There is one build.gradle file for whole projects and one for each modules. 
Need to add below code in the application build.gradle file.

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in build.gradle(Project) :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```